# Why does a Ruby setter return the passed value, rather than the final value of the instance variable?

Tags: ruby, semantics, setter

Ordinarily, Ruby methods return the value of the last expression in the method. For setters of the form `name=`, however, it seems like

Given the following code:

```rb
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def set_bar(v)
    @bar = (v + 1)
  end

  def bar=(v)
    @bar = (v + 1)
  end
end
```

If I call either `bar=` or `set_bar()`, the value of `@bar` is the same:

```rb
f = Foo.new; f.set_bar(1); f.bar
# => 2

f = Foo.new; f.bar=1; f.bar
# => 2
```

The setters' return values, however, are different:

```rb
f = Foo.new; f.set_bar(1)
# => 2
f = Foo.new; f.bar = 1 
# => 1                    
# note: irb in Ruby 2.7+ suppresses this unless you write (f.bar = 1)
```

This persists even if I add an explicit `return`:

```rb
class Foo
  def bar=(v)
    @bar = (v + 1)
    return @bar
  end
end

f = Foo.new; f.bar = 1 
# => 1
```

This is surprising (I know, Matz has said explicitly that Ruby doesn't follow the principle of least surprise) and it's not obviously documented anywhere. Is it documented? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: It's documented under [Methods > Return values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values): _"Note that for assignment methods the return value will be ignored when using the assignment syntax. Instead, the argument will be returned"_. Also see Wikipedia's [Value of an assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Value_of_an_assignment) which shows some applications. (assignment chain and assignment in condition)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks — can you make that an answer so I can upvote it / so it'll be easier for other folks to find the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All assignments always evaluate to the right hand side. It doesn't matter whether it's a

- local variable assignment:

  ```ruby
  foo = 42 #=> 42
  ```
- instance variable assignment

  ```ruby
  @foo = 42 #=> 42
  ```
- class variable assignment

  ```ruby
  @@foo = 42 #=> 42
  ```
- global variable assignment

  ```ruby
  $foo = 42 #=> 42
  ```
- constant assignment

  ```ruby
  FOO = 42 #=> 42
  ```
- abbreviated assignment

  ```ruby
  foo += 42 #=> 42
  foo -= 42 #=> 42
  foo *= 42 #=> 42
  foo /= 42 #=> 42
  foo %= 42 #=> 42
  foo <<= 42 #=> 42
  foo >>= 42 #=> 42
  foo |= 42 #=> 42
  foo &= 42 #=> 42
  foo ||= 42 #=> 42
  foo &&= 42 #=> 42
  ```
- method assignment

  ```ruby
  foo.bar = 42 #=> 42
  ```

Note that the return value is *not* completely ignored:

```ruby
f.public_send(:bar=, 1)
#=> 2
```

> Is it documented?

My favorite piece of documentation for questions like this is the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html). The section you are looking for is 11.4.2.2.5 *Single method assignments*.

> Is there a reason for it?

Consistency and Principle of (matz's) Least Astonishment: all other assignments evaluate to the right-hand side in Ruby. In fact, in pretty much all languages where assignments are expressions, the assignments evaluate to the right-hand side.

So, it makes sense for method assignments to also evaluate to their right-hand side.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from thinking `f.bar = v` was not really "assignment" as such but rather syntactic sugar for `f.send(:bar=, v)`.

I did have a try at checking ISO/IEC 30170:2012, but unfortunately couldn't find a copy that was available publicly or through my institution. :( Do you think you could quote the relevant section in your answer?

Comment: I notice Rubocop flags the explicit return as `Lint/ReturnInVoidContext`, which would have been a clue that `bar=(v)` is not a normal method.

Comment: @DavidMoles: It's not every exciting. Basically, in the syntax description, the expression on the right-hand side is labeled "*operator-expression*", then the second step of the algorithm is "Let *O* be the result of evaluating *operator-expression*" and the last step of the algorithm is "the value of the *assignment-expression* is *O*".